# create a Parquet backed Hive table by using a schema file

Tags: hadoop, hive, schema, avro, parquet

Cloudera [documentation](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/v5-3-x/topics/cdh_ig_hive.html), shows a simple way to "*create a Avro backed Hive table by using an Avro schema file*." This works great. I would like to do the same thing for a Parquet backed Hive table, but the relevant [documentation](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/v5-3-x/topics/cdh_ig_parquet.html) in this case lists out every column type rather than reading from a schema. Is it possible to read the Parquet columns from a schema, in the same way as Avro data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the answer appears to be ***no***. There is an open issue with Hive.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-76

The issue has been active recently, so hopefully in the near future Hive will offer the same functionality for Parquet as it does for Avro.